Conditionals and continuous tenses
I was told that past continuous is used to show that something is already ongoing when contrasted with past simple. For instance.
1 When she entered the room I was sleeping
I agree with that but I was told that the continuous versions act differently in conditionals
2 If I saw  cockroach I might be screaming
I was told by my teacher that sentence 2 may mean two things either I already scream before I even see that monster ;) or that I start right after. I have doubts if my teacher is right. Don't I have to use "I might scream" to show right after?

[I was told by my teacher that sentence 2 may mean two things. Either I was already screaming before I even saw the monster ;) or that I start right after that. I  doubt my teacher is right. Don't I have to use "I might scream" to show right after?]

Your teacher is correct the sentence 'If I saw cockroach I might be screaming' may mean two things.
A minor point I would make is that it should be 'a cockroach' no just 'cockroach'.
I would say it more strongly implies that you may be screaming before you even saw the cockroach than you scream after seeing it because the use of the continuous suggests that when you see the cockroach you already may be in the state of screaming. If you wanted to say that you might be in the state of screaming after seeing it you should say 'If I saw a cockroach I might scream'.
Just one more point is that the sentence itself it a tautology. In logical terms it says If A then (B or not B) and (B or not B) is always true. In English it sound a bit odd to use a conditional with a tautology.

Casual speech is not normally analyzed like mathematical logic. When you use a conditional like this, you're describing the relationship -- seeing a cockroach is correlated with screaming.

Don't worry, I don't go about strictly enforcing the rules of mathematical logic in all my speech it's just as a native English speaker it's something that I automatically pick up on and it sounds weird. Interestingly enough mathematical logic has influence language as it's the reason double negatives are viewed as grammatically incorrect.

As long as you don't just answer "yes" when someone asks a question of the form "Are you X or Y?"
